# get block info using hyperledger fabric java sdk

Tags: java, spring-boot, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am trying to get blockinfo using following two ways.

```
##One way of getting Blockchain block

BlockchainInfo blockinfo = channel.queryBlockchainInfo(userContext);

currentHash1 = Hex.encodeHexString(blockinfo.getCurrentBlockHash());
Hex.encodeHexString(blockinfo.getPreviousBlockHash())

##Another way of iterating over blockchain block

BlockInfo returnedBlock = channel.queryBlockByNumber(blockinfo.getHeight() - 1);
currentHash2 = Hex.encodeHexString(returnedBlock.getDataHash())
```

So using these two ways of getting block info  but the `currentHash` is not same in these cases and if i have to iterate over the blockchain using latter method. No hash is matching with previous hash.

I am not sure if it is suppose to be like this or not but the current block `previousHash` suppose to match `datahash` of previous block.

Comment: Hi, did you get the answer for this question?

Comment: i didn't get the answer yet

Comment: yep, it only return the data hash(not the current block hash indeed) and previous block hash from fabric

Comment: Hi, I just put the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The block does no have it's hash so the SDK can't expose it, but there is a approach to calculate the current block hash from the `BlockInfo`

This is the related codes:

`Hex.encodeHexString(SDKUtils.calculateBlockHash(client,
                        returnedBlock.getBlockNumber(), returnedBlock.getPreviousHash(), returnedBlock.getDataHash()))`

Comment: Hi let me test and i will get back to you. Thanks